# Java libGdx: FreeTypeFontGenerator is not working (Black screen)

Tags: java, android, error-handling, libgdx, desktop-application

I added in a custom font Aller_light.ttf and when I try to run the program with the font drawn with no errors the screen is black, so I'm not sure if its rendering somewhere else off screen or its not rendering at all.
If you could give your 2 cents that would be of great value to me.

**EDIT**
Now it's saying i have a nullPointerExeption

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mygdx.finis.states.MenuState.draw(MenuState.java:43)
    at com.mygdx.finis.states.GameStateManager.draw(GameStateManager.java:31)
    at com.mygdx.finis.Main.render(Main.java:36)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

[This is what should be happening:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Atqp.png)

MenuState Class

```
package com.mygdx.finis.states;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.mygdx.finis.Assets;
import com.mygdx.finis.Main;

public class MenuState extends GameState{

    private SpriteBatch sb;

    private BitmapFont font;

    private int currentItem;
    private String[] menuItems;

    protected MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
    }

    public void init() {

        sb = new SpriteBatch();

        FreeTypeFontGenerator gen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal(null));

        font = gen.generateFont(20);

        menuItems = new String[]{
            "Play"
        };
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
    }

    public void draw() {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(Main.cam.combined);//*** This is where the null pointer starts *********

        sb.begin();
            font.draw(sb, "Quack", Main.WIDTH / 2, Main.HEIGHT / 2);//*** This does not work *******************
        sb.end();

    }

    public void handleInput() {

    }

    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

Main Class

```
package com.mygdx.finis;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.mygdx.finis.states.GameStateManager;

public class Main implements ApplicationListener{

    public static int WIDTH;
    public static int HEIGHT;

    public static OrthographicCamera cam;

    private GameStateManager gsm;

    public void create(){
        WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        cam.translate(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        cam.update();

        gsm = new GameStateManager();
    }

    public void render(){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        gsm.draw();//****** THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE ENDS ******
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height){}
    public void pause(){}
    public void resume(){}
    public void dispose(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that your `SpriteBatch sb` is null. Are you absolutely sure init() is being called?

The only other alternative is that `Main.cam` is null.

It has to be one of those.

Incidentally, this looks odd to me...

```
Gdx.files.internal(null));
```

Why are you doing that?

Comment: Its not null anymore, but it was before because of me fiddling around with stuff. The real issue is now the nullpointerexeption

Comment: How would I make sure init() is called?

Comment: It's your code, so you'd know best! But at a guess, probably right after you instantiate it in the create() method of your Main class.

Comment: BTW - When I say "make sure init() is called" I mean that you should just call it from the place I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, ill let you know how it goes. At the moment I'm restarting because its just pissing me off and I think I did something wrong with the generation.